# PCM Wave (mp3) to text. Not speech to text

Tags: speech-recognition, core-audio, speech-to-text

Without filling this post with bloat.  Want to use speech to text algorithms to convert wav/mp3/whatever audio files to plain text scripts.  Want to do it locally, preferably as a shell command (so audio format can be fudged with ffmpeg).

It seems strange asking this because of siri, and alexa, but all of the software seems to use a live input, not an input file.  Otter offers it, but costs a lot, and I find it hard to justify paying for something that is already open source in one form or other.

I have my eye on sphinx, but before I invest too much time, is there an easier solution that has been worked out?

Running MacOS that still hails under ye High Sierra flag.

Answer (score 0):

Answered: will start simple then elaborate.

I found Vosk to do everything I need: https://alphacephei.com/vosk/

Installation for the python3 library was the most straightforward way for my situation (Mac osx 10.13)

```
$pip3 install vosk
```

Vosk's github has several python examples which served as a good basis for getting started.  Needed to download a model.  Both english models from the site worked, and they go in a subfolder titled "model" where the python scripts lay.

One setback encountered, some of the scripts require ffmpeg, which I did not have.  The script gave a very cryptic set of errors because the subroutine functions attempted to open the file 'ffmpeg' when the bash command was not found.  The python examples do not check for ffmpeg, so make sure it is installed.

I hope this anser helps others!